# Data missing in PostgreSQL dump

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I'm trying to verify that I am actually getting data in my `pg_dump` from a PostgreSQL 9.3 server. I'm specifically running the following to get a dump of my Foreman database:

`pg_dump -Fc foreman -U foreman -h foreman-db -p 5432 > foreman.sql`

I am reading the dump using `pg_restore -l foreman.sql` but when I search for known fqdns of hosts that should be in the `hosts` table, I can not find them.

I'm no DBA, but it seems I'm doing something very wrong or I don't know how to search well enough yet to find data within pg_dump's.

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: If your dump file is small, think you can restore and check directly in database.

Comment: `pg_restore -l` only lists the DDL, not the contents. Also, you might want to prefix that initial "foreman" db name with `-d`, to denote that it's the db.

Comment: Is there a command to use to list the contents as well? Thanks for the tip on the `-d`

Comment: As far as I know you can easily see the contents of the tables if you use `-Fc`. If you export to plaintext (the default, or explicitly via `-Fp`) you'll be able to view the contents with your text editor of choice. If you are by chance looking only for a subset of the data, a sample in effect, have a look at https://github.com/mla/pg_sample

Comment: Seeing the data is the default for `pg_restore` when not replaying into a database.  Just remove the `-l`, no need to add anything.  BTW, it is not customary to use the `.sql` suffix for a custom dump formatted file (the output format of `pg_dump -Fc`).  The usual suffix for a custom dump file is `.dmp`

Answer (score 4):

This turned out to be my own fault and not making sure that the Foreman host had a postgresql93 client installed so that the rake task that imports the database could actually do the `pg_restore` on the valid dump.

I was able to use `pg_dump -Fp` to get the plain text and validate that my data was in there. Thank you everyone for your help. Chalk this one up to a newbie trying to learn Postgres.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to create the dump:

`pg_dump -Fp -U foreman -h foreman-db -p 5432 foreman > foreman.sql`

It will create the dump in plain text format. You can then directly use psql to execute the sql file to restore the dump. No need to use pg_restore.

Also as you are taking a full database dump, i would suggest to first create a database structure dump using pg_dumpall and restore it first, before restoring the data.

Comment: Why would the latter make sense?  Also, `pg_dumpall` takes a dump of every DB that there is (plus the global objects) - how do you know they want this?

Comment: I am assuming the problem here is because of `pg_restore`. So to avoid `pg_restore`, take a text dump and restore directly. Also you have an option to take structure dump of a single database using `pg_dumpall`.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-pg-dumpall.html you cannot dump a single DB using `pg_dumpall`.  I think you mean `pg_dump` instead.